# Mali incompatible DDK on Android OpenCL

Tags: android, arm, opencl, gpu, mali

I was working on an Android app which uses OpenCL on the Galaxy Note 5 which has the Mali T-760 GPU. I pulled the library from the device and got the headers from the Mali OpenCL SDK and everything worked.

I'm trying to build and run the same app on the Galaxy S7 Edge which has the Mali T-880 GPU. I pulled the library from the device and used the same headers as before.

Now I get this error:

E/mali: ERROR: The DDK is not compatible with any of the Mali GPUs on the system.
                                                                                                    The DDK was built for 0x750 r0p1 status range [0..15], but none of the GPUs matched:

E/mali: /dev/mali0 detected as 0x880 r2p0 status 0

It's strange because I pulled the library from device itself and I tried the library from different locations too:

/system/lib/libOpenCl.so

/system/vendor/lib/libOpenCL.so

/system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so

In all cases I get the same error.

What is this DDK?

Where is it specified? In the headers? In the shared object?

What do I need to update in my app to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of strange Android Studio behavior.

I performed project clean and built it with the library link target set to the Mali T-880 library but it still linked somehow the wrong library.

I removed all other libraries, performed a clean build and then it worked.